# FAILED: utils/pango-view.1 while compiling gnome-shell

Tags: gtk, pango

I was trying to build gnome-shell latest using jhbuild:
$jhbuild  build -n gnome-shell
End up with an error as below:

```
I: Install complete: 207 files copied
*** Building pango *** [24/92]
ninja
[108/127] Generating pango-view.1 with a custom command
FAILED: utils/pango-view.1
/usr/bin/help2man --no-info --section=1 --help-option=--help-all '--name="Pango text viewer"' --output=utils/pango-view.1 /home/gta/.cache/jhbuild/build/pango/utils/pango-view
help2man: can't get `--help-all' info from /home/gta/.cache/jhbuild/build/pango/utils/pango-view
Try `--no-discard-stderr' if option outputs to stderr
[117/127] Generating PangoFc-1.0.gir with a custom command
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
*** Error during phase build of pango: ########## Error running ninja   *** [24/92]

  [1] Rerun phase build
  [2] Ignore error and continue to install
  [3] Give up on module
  [4] Start shell
  [5] Reload configuration
  [6] Go to phase "wipe directory and start over"
  [7] Go to phase "configure"
  [8] Go to phase "clean"
choice:
```

Any solution to fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know where this error comes from, but you can

1. Try option 6 "wipe directory and start over"
2. Choose option 4 "start shell", then

   1. Run the failing command manually with slightly modified options:
      `/usr/bin/help2man --no-info --section=1 --help-option=--help '--name="Pango text viewer"' --output=utils/pango-view.1 /home/gta/.cache/jhbuild/build/pango/utils/pango-view`
   2. Run `exit` to exit the shell.
   3. Choose option 1 "Rerun phase build"